Gitlab search is not working on omnibus installation
So I installed gitlab via the omnibus package and set up my site. However when I try to use the search bar on the left hand side navigation bar, nothing appears. It appears that search is not working at all. Other search buttons are working though.For example when I navigate to users and click search, I am able to write a users name and find them. Any thoughts? Thanks
I tried to troubleshoot but it seems there’s nothing of real substance online regarding gitlab basic search.
Just this article explaining the types of gitlab search options:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/search/
